# Instance of a theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is an exercise from the book "*How to Prove It: A Structured Approach*" by Velleman.

**Theorem**. Suppose $b^2 > 4ac$. Then the quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has exactly two real solutions.

The posed question is: To give an instance of the theorem you must specify values for $a,b$ and $c$, but not $x$. Why?

In school we learned that the discriminant must always be positive for the quadratic equation to be positive and we called $a,b$ and $c$ parameters of the equation and not variables, but I don't think this is the case here I think.

My answer would be that since the theorem is structured as

**Hypothesis.** $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, b^2 > 4 a c$

**Conclusion.** $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:$ $ax^2 + b x + c =0 $ has exactly two real solutions.

Then $a,b$ and $c$ are free variables and $x$ is a bound variable since the universal quantifier binds variables. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Another way of stating the same theorem is:

*Theorem*: Let $ax^2+bx+c=0$ be a quadratic equation. If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are chosen such that $b^2 > 4ac$, then there are exactly two real values of $x$ satisfying the equation.

Hopefully that makes the answer to your question clearer.